# Is it possible to read the browser's console from a TamperMonkey script?

Tags: javascript, browser, tampermonkey

Specifically, I'm interested in waiting for a page to load completely (`window.addEventListener("load", ...)` works, is there a better alternative with `@run-at`?) and then detect if any code 410 "Failed to load resource" errors were thrown. The HTML of the specific page I'm trying to monitor is identical to that of a working page, what I don't know is if TS/GS has access to these responses somewhere.

Comment: no, you can not "read" the console

Comment: Well, to get values from the console, if console.log, console.error, etc. is called, you can override the logging with `console._log = console.log; console.log = function() {/* do your own processing */ this._log(...arguments); }`, but i don't think this is what the OP is wanting, because I think that errors are run by native processes so this can't intercept these calls